# Search for local extrema

Tags: analysis, maxima-minima

Investigate for local extrema (don't forget to check for maximum/minimum) the following function:
$F(x,y,z) = \frac{xy + xz^2 + y^2z}{xyz} + x +1$
To specify all the points of local maxima and minima.Response to justify.

I used the standard method for solving this problem: I found partial derivatives and critical points, then I used the Hesse matrix and the Sylvester criterion to find out which of them were the maxima and minima.
There are points : $M_1 = (-1;1-1)$
$M_2 = (1;1;1)$. Where M2 is local minimum, M1 is local maximum. But I am not sure that this is all, and I do not know what additional analysis is needed to show that there are no more points.

Comment: Why do you think that there are other local extrema? Knowing however that $f$ is not continuous at the origin.

Comment: My concern is that the function is defined everywhere except {0;0;0}, in fact we are looking for extremes on an unlimited set, we need to somehow show that there are no others.

Comment: You should precise what you're looking for. Do you need to evaluate the range of $f$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On $D= \mathbb R^3 \setminus \{(0,0,0)\}$, $f$ is smooth. So the local extrema are given by critical points and Hesse matrix on the open subset $D$. And you said that you found those. Good!

Now $$\lim\limits_{t \to 0^+} f(t,t,t) = \infty \text{ and } \lim\limits_{t \to 0^-} f(t,t,t) = -\infty.$$

So $f$ is not bounded.

Comment: This is great! You said that the function tends to infinity and minus infinity. It turns out that these limit values are the global maxima and minima on the value area?

Comment: You have to take care here! If you're looking for [critical points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(mathematics)), then those are the ones you found. And the Hesse matrix is your friend to determinate if those points are maximum, minimum (or none). Now, $f$ **is not defined** at $(0,0,0)$. What I'm saying is that however, on some paths, $f$ can reach infinite values. All depends on **what you're looking for** precisely.

Answer (score 0):

Since $F$ has partial derivatives for all $(x,y,z)$ with $xyz\ne 0$, the local extremum points satisfy $F_x=0, F_y=0, F_z=0$. Solving this system, we obtain that the possible extremum points are $M_1=(-1,1,-1)$ and $M_2=(1,1,1)$. There are no other candidates because these are all the solutions to the system, and the partial derivatives exist for all $(x,y,z)$ in the domain of $F$.

So, the next step is to check whether $M_1$ and $M_2$ are extremum points using the Hessian. Based on what you say, you've already done this part.